# Tracking 2D positioning with IMU Sensor

Tags: c, math, accelerometer, sensors, gyroscope

I am using a miniature car and I want to estimate the position. We can not use GPS modules and most of the tracking systems that I saw, are using IMU senson with the GPS module. In our car we are able to find our exact correct location with image processing but for some parts that dont have enough markings we can not do this. So we want to use the IMU as backup for our positioning. so as long as the positioning is close is good for us.

And we are only interested in our 2D position since the car is on a flat ground.

I am using a IMU 9DOF sensor and I want to calculate my movement. I have seen some amazing works with IMU for tracking body movements but no code or simple explanation is anywhere about it. So basically I have the reading from accelerometer, gyro and magnetometer. I also have orientation in quarternions. From the device I am getting also the linear acceleration but even when I am not moving it in any direction the values are not 0 which is really confusing.

Can you please help me how to approach this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You have three linear accelerations. What 2D coordinate system do you want? And are you aware that an accelerometer measures gravity, so it will only read zero in free fall? Anyway, twice-integrating acceleration to get position is essentially impossible without additional constraints.

Comment: I would measure the heading of the car and its speed by measuring the rpm of the wheels. Trying to integrate the acceleration twice is a dead end, I wouldn't try to do that.

Comment: how about the gyro and orientation?

Comment: Agreed with Ali, if your wheels have good traction then you should be measuring those. If you only want to fill brief gaps between image sensor readings, then the IMU might be sufficient, but you still have to synchronize the data streams from IMU and camera. I found the C++ Eigen library very helpful in my project; it makes geometric integration very easy. But if you find gravity confusing, IMUs just might not be for you.

Answer (score 0):

- You don't need quaternions, but vectors here.
- you should turn your measured acceleration vector according to gyro orientation. So, you'll have exactly accelerations components along X,Y,Z axes
- Count the distances change along axes by double integrating the acceleration components. First integral - speed, second - coordinates.

As for integrating, look for algorithms at [Knuth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Art_of_Computer_Programming) - he is the best.

But all that works only if you are on the flat Earth. Ok for 20-30km, but bad for hundreds of them. If you need coordinates for a region, you have the whole maths on the sphere. And if distances are of thousands kilometers, you have to take into account, that the Earth is an ellipsoid really. You need a very qualified specialist in maths for geodesy(geomatics), high precision geodesy for large distances (astro-geodesy), another specialist in gyro and accelerometers. Maybe you'll find a universal one - in older sea surveyors there are such specialists. Or somebody from the space geodesy. Don't think you can simply read it from books - you need a pair of Master degrees for it.

And even the flat variant is much more hard than you think - you have to take into account errors and make huge countings and use some special practical methodics for detecting and limiting them. Here a mathematician/surveyor consultant could be enough.

The main problem is that surveyors usually are weak in maths and mathematicians don't do survey :-). These specialists are REALLY rare. I had been doing it myself, but now I can't even recommend you somebody - here in Czech rep there is no use for such specialists.